# Symfony 2.8: isScopeActive deprecation after update to 2.8.0 from 2.7.7

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I've updated to symfony 2.8 from 2.7.7 and i get this deprecation:

> The Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::isScopeActive
>   method is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0.

I use this call in a twig extension class:

```
class TemplateHelper extends \Twig_Extension {

    private $request;

    private $container;


    /**
     * constructor
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container){
        $this->container = $container;

        if( $this->container->isScopeActive('request') ){
            $this->request = $this->container->get('request');
        }
    }
    //...functions
    }
```

Firstly i delete the isScopeActive check, but i get an exception when i run the symfony cache clear:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InactiveScopeException]
>   You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope
>   ("request").

Is there any way to replace the isScopeActive check?

Thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply inject `request_stack` instead of `request` and call [getCurrentRequest()](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RequestStack.html#method_getCurrentRequest).

Comment: Is this a like-for-like replacement, i.e. `$this->container->isScopeActive('request')` to be replaced with `$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()`?