# Symfony 2.8: concept of container scopes is deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

after update to Symfony 2.8, I found this deprecation warning:

> The concept of container scopes is deprecated since version 2.8 and
>   will be removed in 3.0. Omit the third parameter. (5 times)

stack from synfony profiler:

```
Container::set() (called from bootstrap.php.cache at line 2284)
Container::leaveScope() (called from bootstrap.php.cache at line 3309)
ContainerAwareHttpKernel::handle() (called from InlineFragmentRenderer.php at line 85)
InlineFragmentRenderer::render() (called from AbstractSurrogateFragmentRenderer.php at line 67)
AbstractSurrogateFragmentRenderer::render() (called from FragmentHandler.php at line 136)
FragmentHandler::render() (called from LazyLoadingFragmentHandler.php at line 75)
LazyLoadingFragmentHandler::render() (called from HttpKernelExtension.php at line 76)
HttpKernelExtension::renderFragmentStrategy() (called from 75b45c481663ac387bc00d9fd8410a46d20e8cbd1078cf7080b74c14e0f1646d.php at line 150)
__TwigTemplate_7076dec1ac0b55b511bbafc8efae5ac640a2c81a9440de2d401f56087dac1203::doDisplay() (called from classes.php at line 7070)
Twig_Template::displayWithErrorHandling() (called from classes.php at line 7051)
Twig_Template::display() (called from d6304ceab492b2a79d826c9d0750a0561bd3706805e4b6ba8f6631e642482647.php at line 133)
__TwigTemplate_980e572e5866e3173c00b4eb28b4e98ddd449060d3a5249c89569efd2680ba06::block_body() (called from classes.php at line 6966)
Twig_Template::displayBlock() (called from a77399988fd8ed31a7e604fea362bdf6567e5faa69fc6b586cbc010a644f717a.php at line 106)
__TwigTemplate_bf78b5c026524d55ca52358963b690a762081ab3d9e87942755d0900f1be6071::doDisplay() (called from classes.php at line 7070)
Twig_Template::displayWithErrorHandling() (called from classes.php at line 7051)
Twig_Template::display() (called from d6304ceab492b2a79d826c9d0750a0561bd3706805e4b6ba8f6631e642482647.php at line 32)
__TwigTemplate_980e572e5866e3173c00b4eb28b4e98ddd449060d3a5249c89569efd2680ba06::doDisplay() (called from classes.php at line 7070)
Twig_Template::displayWithErrorHandling() (called from classes.php at line 7051)
Twig_Template::display() (called from classes.php at line 7058)
Twig_Template::render() (called from TwigEngine.php at line 50)
TwigEngine::render() (called from TwigEngine.php at line 72)
TwigEngine::render() (called from TwigEngine.php at line 97)
TwigEngine::renderResponse() (called from Controller.php at line 185)
```

how do fix this deprecation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 2.8: isScopeActive deprecation after update to 2.8.0 from 2.7.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136957/symfony-2-8-isscopeactive-deprecation-after-update-to-2-8-0-from-2-7-7)

Comment: It's not the same, i ask the question you mention, are two different deprecation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if You want to fix request scope then remove scope from service declaration and inject **request_stack** service into your service.
if You want to fix prototype scope then change it according to http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/service_container/shared.html

Comment: Yes, from 2.8 services needs request stack

Comment: Is this a like-for-like replacement, i.e. `$this->container->isScopeActive('request')` to be replaced with `$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()`?